# String Representation of Model for StackedInlineAdmin in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Is there any way to change the string representation of the model just for single `StackedInlineAdmin`?

Like currently it shows: [image: Current image]

for `__str__`

```
def __str__(self):
    """
    Return string representation of ApplicationFrom objects.

    :return: str
    """
    return '{} - {}'.format(str(self.person), dict(FORM_TYPES)[self.form_type])
```

But I want the last modified date with it as well, just in this inline admin.

Like this: [image: desiged behaviour]

For this behavior, I can change the `__str__` method of the model to

```
def __str__(self):
    """
    Return string representation of ApplicationFrom objects.

    :return: str
    """
    return '{} - {} - {}'.format(str(self.person), dict(FORM_TYPES)[self.form_type], get_standard_date_time_format(self.modified_at))
```

But the old string representation of this model is currently being used in its own admin and other places in codebase well.

What is want is that I should be able to update the string representation of the model just for this admin. We can update the string representation of the model for dropdowns in admin using `label_from_instance` by overriding `formfield_for_foreignkey` but I can't find a way to update its representation in StackedInlineAdmin.